# ApplicationContext import in spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies

I'm learning Spring from this tutorial:

http://courses.caveofprogramming.com/courses/the-java-spring-tutorial/lectures/38024

In this tutorial, instructor downloads spring dependencies (spring-beans, spring context, spring-core) in version 3.2.3.RELEASE.

and then writes this code:

```
package com.caveofprogramming.spring.test;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");

      Person person = (Person)context.getBean("person");
      person.speak();
}
}
```

When I use: spring-context, spring-beans and spring-core in last version 4.3.3.RELEASE then ApplicationContext import doesn't work.  It works when I change it to the old version. "Doesn't work" means that eclips doesn't know what I should import when I write "ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");" and when I write "import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext" by myself it's underline.

What should I do to import ApplicationContext with newest version dependencies?

Edit:
This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
ApplicationContext cannot be resolved to a type
FileSystemXmlApplicationContext cannot be resolved to a type

at com.caveofprogramming.spring.test.App.main(App.java:10)
```

and this is my pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.caveofprogramming.spring.test</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-tutorial-5</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Edit 2: I also saw that program accepts 4.1.1.RELEASE version. Mabye the newest version of dependencies isn't necessary?  I'm just starting with Spring and everyone says that I should work on the newest version.

Edit 3;

The only solution which I found is using spring-context 4.1.1.RELEASE

Comment: Include the exact pom.xml you're using. Also describe the problem in detail, "import doesn't work" is not specific enough.

Answer (score 2):

Either add these jars in your class path  org.springframework.context.support-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar and org.springframework.context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar

Or add this dependency if you are using maven and update the project.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>  
 <version>4.x.x.RELEASE</version>    
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add dependency

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.x.x</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have all dependencies. I edited my post and added this information

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem with eclipse, especially if you are using an older version. Eclipse used to have issues with Maven projects, when you added new dependencies.

You can force Eclipse to update it's Maven dependencies by right clicking your project and selecting Maven->Update project

[image]

After that your project should compile just fine:
[image]

PS: Check the [current documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-instantiation) for up-to-date setup of XML-based application context setup

Comment: My Eclipse version: 4.6.0 (Neon). 
"Update project..." doesn't work. I also deleted and then imported existing maven project without result. Program works when I use 4.1.1.RELEASE spring dependencies version. It will be huge mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

I added this in my `pom.xml` file inside the **dependencies** tag.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.7</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

What it does is that it downloads the `spring-context-5.3.7.jar` file from which ApplicationContext class can be imported.
Hope it works for u too.

Here is my `pom.xml` file for better reference.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.Sharma</groupId>
  <artifactId>NachoVarga</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>NachoVarga</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.7</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.7</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after adding spring context dependencies in pom

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).