# ApplicationContext not being recognized even after adding Maven dependency

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, classpath, maven-dependency

I started a course on spring boot and I am at dependency injection.
I ran into a problem with `ApplicationContext` which I can't seem to resolve:
[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jw3L.png)

I added the maven dependency as you can see in the pom file:
[pom file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZo7T.png)

But it still doesn't recognize the `ApplicationContext` and I cannot find a solution anywhere.

EDIT: whole pom.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>DependencyInjectionDemo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>DependencyInjectionDemo</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.12</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Probably best to showcase your pom.xml...you are probably not setting up all the proper springboot dependencies..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly add `spring-context` dependency, since it is a transitive dependency of `spring-boot-starter`. Other than that it seems fine to me, but we can do three things:

1. Check that you are actually importing `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext` and not some other class;
2. Force the reload of all your dependencies in IntelliJ (right click your project --> Maven --> Reload project);
3. Clear your `.m2` folder (or at least `org/springframework` sub-path folder inside it). You might have some corrupted JARs in there.

Comment: The potentially corrupted Spring dependencies in the local Maven-repository (`.m2` folder) are in sub-path `org/springframework` (Java's dot-separator in package namespaces is resolved as sub-folder in the file-system: `.` becomes `/` on MacOS/Linux and backslash \  on Windows).

Comment: Thanks @hc_dev for the hint. Once again copying and pasting lead me into a mistake :D

Answer (score 0):

From given screenshots I assume, you are using a Maven-project in IntelliJ.

#### Adding imports from classpath

Try to import the class [`org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) in the java class where your `main` method is (as shown in screenshot).

Usually IntelliJ should find the class `ApplicationContext` in your classpath. From your given POM and dependency `spring-boot-starter` the classpath should contain the class.

See:
[ApplicationContext import in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39702430/applicationcontext-import-in-spring)

#### Re-importing Maven dependencies

As [João suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69967874/5730279) try [*reimporting*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html#maven_reimport) by context-action on your POM file (CTRL + SHIFT + O).

See:

- [Import Maven dependencies in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454822/import-maven-dependencies-in-intellij-idea)
- [Maven dependencies | IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-dependencies.html#maven_import_dependency)

#### Repair actions

In case nothing of the above work, either your IntelliJ project notconfigured correctly, or something got out of sync between IntelliJ and Maven. Then try following repair-actions (in order listed below):

1. Run `mvn clean install -U` (see [--update-snapshots](https://dzone.com/articles/using-mavens-u-command-line)), either from IntelliJ's Maven tools or terminal, as explained in
   [Force re-download of release dependency using Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959499/force-re-download-of-release-dependency-using-maven)
2. In IntelliJ's menu select **Invalidate Caches / Restart...** to reindex your project. This can help if IntelliJ and Maven got out of sync.
3. Delete your local Maven repository, usually the (hidden) folder `.m2` in your user's home folder (see [Clear the Maven Cache](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-clear-cache#deleting-thelocal-cache-directory)) and reload/reimport your POM in IntelliJ.